# ¿Cómo acceder a un dato de un arreglo que esta dentro de otro arreglo?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Bien, tengo la siguiente estructura:

> array(10) { ["idTiposDocumentos"]=> array(6) { [0]=>
> object(stdClass)#22 (2) { ["idTipoDocumento"]=> string(1) "1"
> ["descripcion"]=> string(22) "Cédula de ciudadanía" } [1]=>
> object(stdClass)#23 (2) { ["idTipoDocumento"]=> string(1) "2"
> ["descripcion"]=> string(9) "Pasaporte" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#24
> (2) { ["idTipoDocumento"]=> string(1) "3" ["descripcion"]=> string(23)
> "Cédula de extranjería" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#25 (2) {
> ["idTipoDocumento"]=> string(1) "4" ["descripcion"]=> string(3) "Nit"
> } [4]=> object(stdClass)#26 (2) { ["idTipoDocumento"]=> string(1) "5"
> ["descripcion"]=> string(3) "Dni" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#27 (2) {
> ["idTipoDocumento"]=> string(1) "6" ["descripcion"]=> string(3) "RUT"
> } } ["documento"]=> string(5) "10-13" ["nombre"]=> string(0) ""
> ["telefono"]=> string(0) "" ["celular"]=> string(11) "26595496565"
> ["direccion"]=> string(0) "" ["correo"]=> string(0) ""
> ["nombreContacto"]=> string(14) "David" ["diaVisita"]=> string(7)
> "Viernes" ["observaciones"]=> string(0) "" }

La misma se está enviando a una vista de la siguiente forma:

```
$datosProveedor['idTiposDocumentos'] = $this->Model_proveedor->BuscarTiposDocumentos();
//$datosProveedor["idTipoDocumento"] = $this->input->post("tipoDocumento");
$datosProveedor["documento"] = $this->input->post("documento");
$datosProveedor["nombre"] = $this->input->post("nombre");
$datosProveedor["telefono"] = $this->input->post("telefono");
$datosProveedor["celular"] = $this->input->post("celular");
$datosProveedor["direccion"] = $this->input->post("direccion");
$datosProveedor["correo"] = $this->input->post("correo");
$datosProveedor["nombreContacto"] = $this->input->post("nombreContacto");
$datosProveedor["diaVisita"] = $this->input->post("diaVisita");
$datosProveedor["observaciones"] = $this->input->post("observaciones");

$this->load->view('layouts/superadministrador/header');
$this->load->view('layouts/superadministrador/aside');
$this->load->view('superadministrador/formularios/actualizarProveedor_view',array('clave' => $datosProveedor));
$this->load->view('layouts/footer');
```

Lo que quiero es acceder al campo descripción para mostrar el nombre del tipo de documento en un campo de la vista, pero no sé cómo acceder a este campo.

Answer (score 0):

Si bien ya tienes el arreglo formado de `$datosProveedor` puedes pasarlo de 2 formas:

Primera opción, pasar el arreglo directamente a la vista:

```
$this->load->view('superadministrador/formularios/actualizarProveedor_view', $datosProveedor);
```

Y acceder directamente al dato que quieres, que en tu caso dices que es **descripción**, pero en ningún momento muestras el dato **descripción**.

Para acceder por ejemplo a **dirección** lo harías con: `$direccion`

Segunda opción, pasar el arreglo dentro de otro arreglo como tú lo estás haciendo:

```
$this->load->view('superadministrador/formularios/actualizarProveedor_view', array('clave' => $datosProveedor));
```

Para poder acceder en la vista a ese dato lo harías con: `$clave['dirección']`

Comment: muchas gracias lo probaré